# Enigma Find the age of the father and the son

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A slippery enigma.

Here is a speech between a father and his son.
My father can I know your current age.
The father answers: ah my son! When I had the age of your current age, you had yellow hair like the sun.
The son insists, I want to know your age my father.
The father replies: Well, you want to know my age!

- The sum of my current age with the age you had when I had the age of your current age is 40
- The sum of your current age with the age I will have when you have the age of my age is 60 or 120.

The son answers, now I know your age.
Does the son lie?

I think the son lied because we normally find two solutions. What do you think

Comment: This seems to be asking for opinions -- and that's a reason for closure on this site.  If you're asking this as a puzzle it should be on puzzling.stackexchange.com (and I would absolutely check if it's a duplicate there first as I think it will be).  Otherwise you should really make this a proper mathematical question: you could demonstrate the solution and explain why you believe the son lied from an evidentiary position.

Comment: Where did you find this question?

Comment: @MathLover 
 It was in an evening between friends

Comment: There are no two solutions as far as I can see. There is one solution - but that too defies norms and nearly biology too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he is not lying.

x= age of father

y= age of son

x+(y-(x-y))=40

y+(x+(x-y)=60 or 120

y=20 and x=30 or x=60.

Although it is strange someone has a baby at the age of 10, if the father had been 60 years old, then at the age of 20 his son would not have existed, which contradicts the fact that the son had yellow hair when the father was 20 years old. So, the father is 30 years old.

Comment: Oh yes, I did not pay attention to the hair hypothesis was fundamental.